# VM protect failed issue

Tags: memory, memory-management, greenplum

While running a SQL code on Greenplum cluster of 10 servers  we are encountering this issue

Detail: VM protect failed to allocate 517656 bytes from system, VM Protect 7672 MB availabe

Comment: This is not a PostgreSQL error message, so I will remove the PostgreSQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few resources to read up on

Docs: 
https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/6-0/install_guide/prep_os.html

Knowledge Base Article
https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Out-of-memory--VM-Protect-errors

Calculator: 
https://greenplum.org/calc/

hope this helps..